# React-bootstrap Alert is not Re-Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am working on login module. I am using **nodeJs** for my backend services.

## Problem: I want to display a message whenever any error occurred duering login.

For this, i am sending a message to the client on every login request from the server.

1. When client username and password is correct then server sends **"OK"**.

2.When password is incorrect then server sends **"Password do not match!"**.

3. When email is incorrect then server sends **"User is not in the database"**.

## React Code:

#### States

```js
this.state={
            email:'',
            password:'',
            msg:''
        }
```

I have a **Login** component which renders all the input controls and button. In Login component i have a Submit button, input control for **Email** and **Password** .

When User clicks on **Submit** button then i am making a request to the server.

#### Login request:

```js
 axios.post('http://localhost:4000/signin',{
            email:this.state.email,
            password:this.state.password
        })
        .then(response=>{
            if(response.data.msg==='OK'){
                window.location.href='/';
            }else{
                this.setState({
                    msg:response.data.msg
                })
                //alert(response.data.msg);
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

*Every thing is fine from the server. I am getting messages from the server on each success of failed login.*

I am rendering a  Message (`<Message show={true} msg={this.state.msg}/>`) component and passing show={true} and msg={this.state.msg} as props.

#### Message component

```js
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert';

export default class Message extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            show:false
        }
    }
      componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({show:this.props.show})
      }

    handleClose=()=>{
        this.setState({
            show:false
        })
    }
    render(){
        if(this.props.msg.length<4){
        return (<p></p>);
        }
           

        return(
            <div>
                <Alert variant='danger' show={this.state.show} onClose={this.handleClose} dismissible>
                    <Alert.Heading>Oh snap! You got an error!</Alert.Heading>
                    <p>
                        {this.props.msg}
                    </p>
                </Alert>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

All is  i am returning a empty element when message length is less than 4. This ensures me that ***Message*** component will not render when we go to the login page initially or login is success.

#### Main problem:

I go to the  login page and entered wrong email then i got this page.

---

---

[image: Problem image]

---

---

When i clicked on the close button inside the model, then it closes as expected. But, the problem is, when i again enter wrong username or password then i didn't get ***Alert***.

Comment: Try using componentDidUpdate(){
        this.setState({show:this.props.show})
      }
instead of componentDidMount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the state of display is being passed by props, you only get to true when that component mounts, because you have the state change in the function componentDidMount and that will be executed just one time. For this you need to use the componentDidUpdate() function.

You should take in account that using componentDidUpdate is kind of tricky, since it will execute everytime the component updates, you can create an infinite loop with ease, this is why you must have a stop condition. Something like:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      show: false
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    //Only update the state when the current value is different than the incoming value
    if(this.state.show != this.props.show) {
      this.setState({ show: this.props.show })
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Update: Adding functional component version

For this case we can use the `useEffect` hook that will call an effect when any of the variables in the dependency array changes.

```
const MyFunctionalComponent = ({ show }) => { //destructuring show prop
  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false); //our state variable  

  useEffect(() => {
    if(showAlert != show) { //only update when values are different
      setShowAlert(show); //update the state
    }
  }, [show]);

  ...
}
```

Comment: Can you add the Functional Component version of this?

Comment: Hey @MendiSterenfeld I added a functional component version as you requested